# Want to calculate difference between phone time and SQL time, number is not consistant

Tags: java, android, sql, time

So I want to get difference between phone's `System.currentTimeMillis();` and SQL's `"SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURTIME(3)) * 1000"` the result seems to be somewhat similiar ... it's like 110ms, 111, 106, 108, you get the idea.. It's just few ms so it's fine, but I still wonder, shouldn't it be ALWAYS the same? if not, ok, why isn't it? And could it be somehow?

```
rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURTIME(3)) * 1000 - " + System.currentTimeMillis());
if (rs.next()){ diff = rs.getLong(1); }
Log.d("DIFFERENCE",String.valueOf(diff));
```

Comment: The difference could be due to lag in the network between you and the database, or the time it takes for the code to be run in the database.

Comment: You my try `System.currentTimeMillis()` before and after querying the database and check if the value from the database lies between the two values you get. This may also give you an indication of how long the DB query takes.

Answer (score 0):

Both times are coming from different "subsystems":

- One is coming from the database as `SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURTIME(3)) * 1000`. There is overhead in the execution of the SQL statement. This overhead can be minimal, but under heavy OS load, this overhead can be higher (seconds or even minutes).
- The other one is coming directly from the JVM, so it should be instantaneous (mostly). Minimal lag here.

Don't expect them to have exactly the same value. The SQL one will always be lagging behind a little bit (or a lot).